# The tags textfield in the Technologies section of the "Job matching preferences" doesn't expand

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs, developer-story, user-experience

This is what I'm talking about:

[image]

If you add more than three tags it becomes clunky and hard to use since there's no scroll and it doesn't expand. It would be better if it worked like the one in the section where you choose the locations:

[image]

**Note:** If this is part of the Developer Story feature then please let me know so that I can tag it properly.